# Row image changes in listview in android?

Tags: android, image, listview, background

I am developing an android application where I need to manipulate the background image of the rows in listview on certain conditions. Initially when the listview is loaded all works properly. But when I scroll down to the listview and come up again the background image changes. Can someone tell me the reason why its happening so?

Hope to get the reply soon.

Comment: what are the conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out this issue. There were some conditions which were getting changed while scrolling.

Thanks anyways.

Regards

Sunil

Comment: Well, I was not setting the setImageBitmap or such methods to null where images were not available. This was leading to problem while scrolling.